# PTIJ: What is the proper attire for women in Scotland?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Jewish law does not allow women to wear men's clothing.

So, do Scottish Jewish women wear pants?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Why is it a PTIJ - it is a valid Halachic question?

Comment: @alberko I'm not sure what the joke was supposed to be, but the serious answer is that they wear whatever Scottish women wear.

Comment: The Purim Torah answer here must involve Scotch somehow; The Pasuk says *nosen lachmi umeimai*, water + bread = Scotch; ... "ve-shikuyai" even though normally *Shok be'isha erva*, here we give them leggings too; therefore it means that the women who drink Scotch should wear pants.

Comment: I repeat my vote to close. This is not a Purim Torah question.

Comment: In light of the closing, reopening, and more pending close votes on this question, can you clarify why this is not a serious question?

Comment: @Alex -- If you have to explain, it's not funny.  All I can tell you is that over the years I told this joke many times and people laughed.  We don't all have the same sense of humor.  And yes, most PTIJ questions can be construed as real and not tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's funny. It matters if it fulfills the stated policy, which it does not. Tell your non PTIJ jokes elsewhere.

Comment: If you don't like it, delete it.

Comment: I'm not an arbiter of liking or not. I'm here to enforce site policy.

Answer (score 5):

In Scotland, men wear either kilts or trousers, the latter being called [trews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trews). As men may wear either trews or kilts, women may wear neither, due to concerns of קלי גבר. Instead, women are to wear barrels used for the production of whisky, as these קלים are not used for menswear and should a man wear it, we accuse him of having consumed the contents, which is forbidden due to בל תשחית.*

*Using whisky simply to become drunk is תשחית according to many authorities, who hold that good whisky should be reserved for שמחות and עלויי נשמות.